# How to limit results in map function

Tags: python, couchdb

In `Python` I'm using this function to filter data from `CouchDB`:

```
people = "function(doc){if(doc.name==='Jacobian')emit(doc,null)}"
```

But what if I want to get only one document corresponding to `doc.name==='Jacobian'`? How should function look like?

PS. I've heard something about views and that it can be realized through them, but at this moment I want to limit data, using map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map function:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.name)
    emit(doc.name,null)
}
```

request:

```
/:db/_design/:name/_view/:name?key="Jacobian"&include_doc=true
```

Comment: What does exactly force limiting? It seems as if there are two documents with `doc.name==Jacobian`, then both of them will be returned by your map function. What I'm asking about - is the way to limit results. Something that we do in `sql` using `LIMIT N `, or `TOP N `, or `FIRST 10 `

Comment: add the query param ?limit=1 to the url above